# Stripped threads on top mount for shock, is it still usable?

Tags: suspension, shock-absorber, stripped-thread

I have an otherwise brand new shock (KYB KG5551 Gas-a-Just Monotube Shock) that I mistakenly torque gunned the old (OEM) nut onto. This stripped all the threads and it no longer accepts the correct nut, the protective coating is also gone and now it's just raw metal threads.

I've already ordered a replacement, but is there any hope for this one? What can I do with it now?

I don't want to sell it used if nobody else can use it, I don't know if running a die over the threads is a safe idea?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: **DO NOT** sell that to anyone, they could end up getting killed... Unless you have had it completely refurbished...

Comment: Oh for sure, I would only sell them with full disclosure to someone who wants to refurbish them or for scrap

Answer (score 1):

It probably will not hold with die ran over the threads, so I doubt it will be usable. The problem is, even with a new nut on it, the threads are already compromised. A shock works in two directions: compression and extension. The compression side would work fine, but under extension, it will pull a nut across the threads again. You could possibly cut the threads down to the next size, but then you have a thinner stud attached to the shock, which would make it ripe for failure. There's no way to my thinking you could add a new stud onto the shock to replace the old one. The only way to do it would be to weld it into place, which would more than likely compromise the shock internals. To my way of thinking, I'd suggest it's a lost cause.

Comment: One possible option is to approach the manufacturer and ask if they offer a shock absorber rebuild service, I know some do.  They could potentially strip the unit down and replace the plunger part which presents out the top of the unit as the spindle.  It has to be worth at least asking the question.

Comment: Thanks, thats what I was thinking, just wanted to run it past somebody else first. I will contact KYB to see what they say